# SQL Self Join to return non match records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Self Join, I am trying to return non match records matching with where condition.

```
select RxNum,image from OeImage 
where   RxNum in ('100','200','300')
```

In the Table OeImage, i have values for 100,300. I don't have value for 200.

How to return not available records using self join, while Input value is passed by parameter.

Comment: `UNION SELECT 200, null FROM OeImage ` you can add something like this to your query.

Comment: This ain't a join. Also what type is `RxNum` ?

Comment: Data Type for RxNum is Nvarchar

Comment: about how long is that list typically? 3 values like example? 1000 values?

Comment: Input values are around 500. But i can split it as 100 batch.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of non-existing values you're trying to search for is small, you can use `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT '100' RxNum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '200'    
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT '300'
    ) myList
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM OeImage
        WHERE RxNum = myList.RxNum
        )
```

If the list of elements is long or is needed in multiple queries, you can use a [Temp Table variable](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx) like this:

```
DECLARE @myList TABLE (RxNum NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @myList
VALUES ('100')
    ,('200')
    ,('300')

SELECT *
FROM @myList
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM OeImage
        WHERE RxNum = @myList.RxNum
        )
```

Comment: Isn't possible to have one syntax. And in the where condition , can i use in insteadof =. No other alternate than UNION ALL. It is just a manual counting

Comment: @goofyui can you reword that? none of that made sense, sorry

Comment: If you want to select the value '200' as your answer .. it needs to exist as a row somewhere and can't simply be in an `in` clause. This is what these two methods accomplish. Where is the source of this list coming from?